# Get Selected Element based on caret position in contenteditable Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to get the element that the caret is in at any given time within a contenteditable DIV.

So far, I am able to get the caret position within the text.

But I want to go a step further to actually get the element selected. For instance, if the caret is after the first letter in the word `"wombat"` in my example, the solution would also return the `id` of the selected element `"wombatid"` and not just the caret position. Any tips or solutions?

```js
function getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
            start = preCaretRange.toString().length;
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            end = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        }
    } else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", textRange);
        start = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        end = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return { start: start, end: end };
}

function reportSelection() {
  var selOffsets = getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin( document.getElementById("editor") );
  document.getElementById("selectionLog").innerHTML = "Selection offsets: " + selOffsets.start + ", " + selOffsets.end+" <br> Selected Element's id: 'element here'";
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.addEventListener("selectionchange", reportSelection, false);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", reportSelection, false);
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", reportSelection, false);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", reportSelection, false);
};
```

```css
#editor {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid green 1px;
}
```

```html
Select something in the content below:

<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">A <i id="wombatid">wombat</i> is a marsupial native to <b id="australiaid">Australia</b></div>
<div id="selectionLog"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the selected element inside a contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808447/how-to-get-the-selected-element-inside-a-contenteditable-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get ID you can try something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#editor *").forEach(el => el.onclick = e => alert(e.target.id));
```

here `e.target` will be your HTML element, it should work for any HTML element

```js
function getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
            start = preCaretRange.toString().length;
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            end = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        }
    } else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", textRange);
        start = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        end = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return { start: start, end: end };
}

function reportSelection() {
  var selOffsets = getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin( document.getElementById("editor") );
  document.getElementById("selectionLog").innerHTML = "Selection offsets: " + selOffsets.start + ", " + selOffsets.end+" <br> Selected Element's id: 'element here'";
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.addEventListener("selectionchange", reportSelection, false);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", reportSelection, false);
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", reportSelection, false);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", reportSelection, false);
  document.querySelectorAll("#editor *").forEach(el => el.onclick = e => alert(e.target.id));
};
```

```css
#editor {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid green 1px;
}
```

```html
Select something in the content below:

<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">A <i id="wombatid">wombat</i> is a marsupial native to <b id="australiaid">Australia</b></div>
<div id="selectionLog"></div>
```